# "path is not absolute" exception while uploading file in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

`path is not absolute: src/test/resources/testData/twt_Pic.jpg` getting this exception while uploading the file using selenium.

Instead of uploading the file using the native os file explorer, sending the keys to the path file.

The same path used to work during the older version, not sure which version was it.

**Error Log in Chrome:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: path is not absolute: src/test/resources/testData/twt_Pic.jpg
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562713 (dd642283e958a93ebf6891600db055f1f1b4f3b2),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'nagarjunaMBP.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c2e:b816:67ae:922b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.4', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.39.562713 (dd642283e958a9..., userDataDir: /var/folders/g4/dylg4g7s7wb...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 66.0.3359.181, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: bdf391bf16ddbda6c9f73d559404bae7
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:276)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:51)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
    at actions.PublishBroadcast.MediaLibAction.uploadImage(MediaLibAction.java:43)
    at stepDefinitions.Publish.SDMediaLibrary.Upload_an_Image(SDMediaLibrary.java:43)
    at ✽.When Upload an Image(features/publish/mediaLibrary/MediaLibrary.feature:11)
```

**Error Log for Firefox:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: File not found: src/test/resources/testData/twt_Pic.jpg
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'nagarjunaMBP.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c2e:b816:67ae:922b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.4', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 60.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 53177, moz:profile: /var/folders/g4/dylg4g7s7wb..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, platformVersion: 17.5.0, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: 7c932de3-ea6a-a143-a7b4-bf7dfa3e2660
```

**Project Structure:**

1. Project/src/main/java - Contains actions, UI element repository, Step Defenitions. From where the file is being called
2. Project/src/test/java - Contains only runner class
3. Project/src/test/resources/customLib - Contains drivers
4. Project/src/test/resources/features - Contains feature files
5. Project/src/test/resources/testData - Contains the test data including the file which i'm trying to call here.

Comment: Add more details

Comment: @Prany, uploading the file using the method of sending the path of the file using "sendKeys" method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try creating a `File` instance and getting the absolute path from there.

```
File file = new File("src/test/resources/testData/twt_Pic.jpg");
yourElement.sendKeys(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 1):

the error message is clearly telling you what's wrong.

you are trying to upload `src/test/resources/testData/twt_Pic.jpg`, which is a relative path to an image.  As the error states, it must be an absolute path (not relative).  Replace the path and try again.

Comment: this exact path was working in an older version of selenium. but trying to understand and a workaround so that when the code runs on different machines, I do not have to look for the paths. As `src/test/resources/testData/twt_Pic.jpg` resides in the project, it will be easy

Comment: convert it to an absolute path in your code, then pass the absolute path to sendKeys()

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in python and I solved with this:

```
abs_path = os.path.abspath("relative_path_to_file.jpg")
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"input").send_keys(abs_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

As (possibly) you are using *Maven* you need to provide the relative *path* with respective your *Maven Project* directory as follows:

```
./src/test/resources/testData/twt_Pic.jpg
```

Where `.` refers to the *Parent Project Directory*

Comment: Can you clean up the _Project_ space through `Clean` & `Rebuild All` through your IDE and retest?

Comment: still getting the `unknown error: path is not absolute: ./src/test/resources/testData/twt_Pic.jpg`

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy Can you update the question with the directory hierarchy/structure of `/testData/twt_Pic.jpg` from _Project Level_?

Comment: Updated the project structure. Please check if it helps

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```java
String path = "src/test/resources/testData/twt_Pic.jpg";
File file = new File(new File(path).getAbsolutePath());
```